# How to find vector length of each string element in a given vector

Tags: scheme

Am new to SICP and am writing a function length-of-vector-elements that takes such a vector as an argument and returns a vector of lengths

Here is so far what i have tried but not giving the results

```
#lang racket
(define colors
(vector "red" "orange" "yellow" "green" "blue" "indigo" "violet"))

(define (length-of-vector-elements vct)
  (vector-map vector-length vct))
(length-of-vector-elements colors)
```

The desired output is: `(length-of-vector-elements colors) => #(3 6 6 5 4 6 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of `colors` are strings, not vectors, so you have to use [`string-length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._string-length%29%29):

```
#lang racket

(define colors
  (vector "red" "orange" "yellow" "green" "blue" "indigo" "violet"))

(define (length-of-vector-elements vct)
  (vector-map string-length vct))

(length-of-vector-elements colors)
```

=> `#(3 6 6 5 4 6 6)`